# With CMake, how can I "install an alias" to a library?

Tags: build, cmake, alias

I'm using CMake for a library, with a target named `foo`. But - I also want users of the library to be able to refer to it as `foo_altname`. I tried doing this:

```
add_library(foo_alt ALIAS foo)
install(
  TARGETS foo foo_altname
  EXPORT strf)
# etc. etc.
```

... but this triggers an error! :

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:78 (install):
  install TARGETS given target "foo_altname" which is an alias.
```

what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of "installing" an alias for being exported to the user, you may **create** an alias in the *main configuration file* which is being installed.

Remember: It is you (as a project's developer) who writes the **main configuration file**, which after installation will be found by `find_package`. Using `EXPORT` option for different commands you just ask CMake to generate *additional* files, which will be included into the main one.

**fooConfig.cmake**:

```
# Include the file generated by CMake. This would define IMPORTED target 'foo'.
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/fooTargets.cmake")

# Additional declarations for a user

# E.g. create an alias
add_library(foo_altname ALIAS foo)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# ...
install(
  TARGETS foo
  EXPORT fooTargets)

# Assume all configuration files to be installed into lib/cmake/
install(
  EXPORT fooTargets
  DESTINATION "lib/cmake"

# Install a hand-written configuration file
install(
  FILES fooConfig.cmake
  DESTINATION "lib/cmake"
```

Note, that if the alias is just a **prefixed** target's name, then you may use NAMESPACE option for `install(EXPORT)` command:

```
install(
  EXPORT fooTargets
  DESTINATION "lib/cmake"
  NAMESPACE alt::
```

This would provide IMPORTED target `all::foo` instead of plain `foo`.

More details about creating configuration files see in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-packages.7.html).

Comment: Actually, I'm aiming to completely avoid writing configuration files myself, in favor of having them generated... see also [this CMake issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19591).

Comment: Yes, I know (from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61815038/how-do-i-introduce-find-dependency-calls-into-my-generated-foo-config-cmake-file#comment109352764_61815038) to the related question) that you are proponent for **auto-generated configuration files**. Unfortunately, current CMake doesn't work as you want. The [referenced issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19591) and some [other ones](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18634) are just confirmation of that. Do you really want to affect on CMake developers by posting on Stack Overflow?