# How do I introduce find_dependency calls into my generated foo-config.cmake file?

Tags: c++, cmake, installation, dependencies

I have a CMake project named `foo`. In its `CMakeLists.txt`, and among other commands, I have:

```
install(
        EXPORT foo_export
        DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/foo"
        NAMESPACE "foo::"
        FILE foo-config.cmake
)
```

(and also a `write_basic_package_version_file()` call later on.)

Now, I want `foo-config.cmake` to also check for a dependency `bar` of `foo`, with `find_dependency()`. How do I do that, other than by replacing the `.cmake` file generation with something manual?

Notes:

- I'm interested both in the case of `bar` being a requried dependency and the case of it being optional.
- I would rather not write a `foo-config.in` unless it's the only option.

Comment: It is not CMake who should generate `foo-config.cmake` which can be used by `find_package(foo)`. It is you, as the project's author, who should create this file and include all other files generated by CMake. E.g. resulted file of `write_basic_package_version_file` is not used by CMake: it should be included into `foo-config.cmake` manually. Exactly your `foo-config.cmake` could use `find_dependency` for locate dependent packages. See that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51293903/3440745) on similar question for more info.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Huh? CMake _does_ generate the `foo-config.cmake` that other project authors use to avail themselves of my installed `foo`. Your other answer doesn't make sense, sence your example shows how CMake can generate that file just fine (other than additional custom commands which I usually don't want to add).

Comment: Exactly that approach is described in [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html). I mention it in my answer. Have you read the doc?